# how can i append data from two queries into one table? run-time error: 3061 expected 2 occurred

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm new to code-world, and i need your help. I am getting the "run-time error: 3061 expected 2".

Note that "QC_MonthlyAm4CuID_Tr" and "QC_YrlyAm4CuID_Tr" are queries with not editable data. And they depend on a combobox to select a parameter.

I tried many solution found on web and failed.
I also tried other options than dbOpenDynaset and also failed.

any suggestions?

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rsM As Recordset
Dim rsY As Recordset
Dim lngID As Long
Dim strCriteria As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("T_CrofServices", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsM = db.OpenRecordset("QC_MonthlyAm4CuID_Tr", dbOpenDynaset)  `*here i get the error*`
Set rsY = db.OpenRecordset("QC_YrlyAm4CuID_Tr", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: Why would you append data from a query in to a table? This smells like bad database design. Can you describe what your end goal is?

Comment: @HackSlash I need to store the data got from the queries since they vary.

Comment: But the data for a query comes FROM a table so it's already there. You should never repeat data. A query can always be run again. You can JOIN queries together in any order. You should really study database design before you get too deep in to something that becomes unsupportable.

Comment: You might be looking at an XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/
If you tell us what you are doing and why then we might find the answer.

Comment: @HackSlash, ok i'll explain.

Comment: @HackSlash, 
i have to select month and year from end-user form in order to automatically create invoices and save this selected month and year in the same record, in addition to the other fields: date(), amount... etc

And, some customers doesn't have to get invoices in this selected month and year (comparing with a date field in customers table)..

what I've done is entering the selected date as Expr in query (to be added to the invoice) and added into criteria of customer's date.

I got all the results i want, and i need to save them as invoices.

have I explained well?

Comment: Yes. Invoices would be Report objects: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-reports-in-access-e0869f59-7536-4d19-8e05-7158dcd3681c

Comment: You can also have an Invoice table that points to records in other tables. You would never copy data from one table to another. You would merely store the ID of the related data. This is what database relationships are.

Comment: @HackSlash bro i am not copying data.. I am creating it!
these invoices I'm creating with queries and involving calculations have to be saved for later use, ex: they include a yes/no field to be selected later as paid. And many other stuff. can reports do that?

Comment: I need to automatically generate invoices for a number of customers based on their monthly or yearly services, and store these invoices for later use.
the only copied data will be the customer ID (primary key) and the price of the specific service in that specific date (for prices of services vary from time to time).

Comment: @abbas It is not clear from the code or your description what you are trying to do and what you have tried to get there. Please update your question.

Comment: Please read this blog post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the *parameter values* of the queries:

```vb
Dim db      As DAO.Database
Dim qdM     As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qdY     As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs      As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsM     As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsY     As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

Set qdM = db.QueryDefs("QC_MonthlyAm4CuID_Tr")
Set qdY = db.QueryDefs("QC_YrlyAm4CuID_Tr")
qdM.Parameters(0).Value = <ValueFromYourFirstCombobox>
qdM.Parameters(1).Value = <ValueFromYourSecondCombobox>
qdY.Parameters(0).Value = <ValueFromYourThirdCombobox>
qdY.Parameters(1).Value = <ValueFromYourForthCombobox>

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("T_CrofServices", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsM = qdM.OpenRecordset()  `*here i get the error*`
Set rsY = qdY.OpenRecordset()
```

Comment: thank you this worked, but lead into another problem.. now my code is running unstoppable! it added almost 999999 records into the table and lead to crash.. I'm using loop to add records, should i use something else?

Comment: Somehow your loop is missing a stop condition. If that is missing, it will behave as you describe.